# DataGridComboBoxColumn doesn't display my collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I just want to do a simple thing, I just want to show my list of versions into a combobox in a datagrid.

The column "Versions" displays "Collections"... and I don't know why!

Here the code into my xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridTableau"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserAddRows="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding }"
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sofware" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Software}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Version" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Versions}">
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And into xaml.cs :

```
public ObservableCollection<ElementTableau> Elements;

        public VueEtapeSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Elements = new ObservableCollection<ElementTableau>();
            List<string> versions = new List<string>();
            versions.Add("3.0");
            versions.Add("3.1");
            Elements.Add(new ElementTableau("Excel", versions));

            this.DataGridTableauEKs.DataContext = Elements;
        }

        public class ElementTableau
        {
            private string sofware;

            public string Software
            {

                get { return software; }
                set { software = value; }
            }

            private List<string> versions;

            public List<string> Versions
            {

                get { return versions; }
                set { versions = value; }
            }

            public ElementTableau(string software, List<string> versions)
            {
                this.software = software;
this.versions=versions

            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `ItemsSource` using a style:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sofware" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Software}" />
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Versions}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Versions}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Binding the `ItemsSource` property of the column doesn't work, because it is evaluated in the context of the column itself which has no parent FrameworkElement. Using the style instead sets the `ItemsSource` as soon as the ComboBox is being rendered. The ComboBox is integrated in the logical tree and its DataContext can be evaluated, that's why it works.

**Edit:**

To bind your selected items, add some setters like this:

```
<Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedVersion}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. But How can I bind the selected item? I put a property in my ElementTableau which is "VersionSelected". Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I was tried this solution.